# How to run WebApi project on IIS using only command line?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api, deployment

I have a `WebApi` project which has used `.net 4.5`. I am trying run this only using ***cmd***. I have followed many links, blogs etc. which explains to do so using `iisexpress` commands, but I still couldn't find a helpful answer.

Can some one please post the complete steps to do so ***preferably starting from*** the point ***'how to add*** `iisexpress` ***to path (so that cmd knows it)'***.??

Comment: Does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment not cover what you asked?